# Memory usage out-of-control with shell command, but not with shell script

Tags: memory, btrfs, virtual-memory, fish

[Linux Mint 20.1, 16GB RAM, 16GB swap]

I recently converted my system - root and backup partitions - to BTRFS. I've been experimenting with archiving some of root's snapshots to my backup drive, but the memory usage of the following commands brought my system to its knees:

```
btrfs send /.snapshots/98/snapshot | btrfs receive /media/backups/@root/.snapshots/98
```

This command sucked up nearly 20 GB of RAM, completely freezing my system a couple of times in the process. My root partition is using about 11 GB, not including snapshots.

My next test was using the same command within a script (original reason was to test `systemd-run` and setting memory limits), like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

btrfs send /.snapshots/98/snapshot | btrfs receive /media/backups/@root/.snapshots/98
```

Running this script used a grand total of 8 MB and was 4x faster. Just to be sure I was running in the same testing environment, I made sure that the original backup snapshot was deleted and committed (`btrfs subvol delete -Cv`). I also ran the same tests with bash, got the same results.

*UPDATE: just to make each test the same, I ran both again - in `fish` and `bash` - using `/usr/bin/btrfs` instead of my alias (to `sudo btrfs`). The results were the same.*

*UPDATE #2: my previous update was in error.*

Comment: have you tried again the first one after running the script? to see if something else changed ? On the top of my head I could maybe see the influence of running in an interactive shell for the first one... so maybe there are a different environment (locale? TERM and somehow btrfs goes through terminal functions?) .. but all unlikely. You could try:  strace-ing those process and compare (... but you'll need lots of space to store strace output). and compare:   printf "%s\n" "$PATH"  in both ? to see if you start the same command... (or which btrfs, or  type -all btrfs )

Comment: I will test this again after my next reboot, to make sure that I have a clean environment.

Comment: I meant: if you executed the script after the shell one, maybe something occured that made the 2nd pass faster? so just try just after the bash one and see if the latter try is also faster?

Comment: I tried it in reverse - script first, then shell - and the results were the same. I've incorporated the script into my python backup program; if that works, then I'm not going to worry about it.

Comment: In fish shell this could happen if `btrfs` is a function, which would need to buffer its output. Does `type btrfs` show something other than just an executable path?

Comment: I made it an alias to `sudo btrfs`, so I can see your point. Unfortunately, in at least one test with `bash`, I got the same results.

Comment: if fish is similar to bash:   **command btrfs**  # bypasses function and alias of that name, and start the first command with that name found in its cache or in $PATH if it haven't run it yet.   # I don't recall the way to clear the cache (in bash) (and I never installed fish.. check their info or man pages) (no need to clear the cache, unless you have another /path/to/btrfs that you may have run in that same shell session)

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: @OlivierDulac - I am in your debt. After revisiting my tests, I did *not* run btrfs as I had thought. Running `sudo /usr/bin/btrfs` works exactly the same as via script. Please post as an answer.

Comment: I believe @ridiculous-fish pointed out the main reason why a function would be slower, so I think this person should post as an answer?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish - I'll accept your answer when posted (see my previous comments - I credited the wrong person).